# Calculating DC Brushless Motor Position

Tags: motor, control, motor-controller, back-emf

I am using a brush-less motor in one of my projects and I need a decent method of sensing the motor position so I know what coils to turn on and off. I looked a bit into sensing Back-EMF, but I did not find anything that would suit my needs. I thought about a method to monitor the current so when the magnets finish moving toward the active coil, there should be a spike in current being drawn since the magnet is no longer running around the coil and is no longer acting as a generator.
I am using an Arduino, so is there any way I would be able to sense this spike in current? Is there a better method (excluding Hall Effect Sensors) then the one I just described? Would my method allow for the motor to function properly?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you against using the BEMF commutation technique?

Comment: I don't want to have to turn the coil off to sense the BEMF. I guess if that is the best way I could figure out a way.

Comment: Is this a 3-phase BLDC?

Comment: Yes, it has 3 wires for the coils

Comment: If it's a brushless 3-phase BLDC, measuring the BEMF to detect zero-crossing while implementing a standard 6-step commutation sequence is your only viable option. Are you interested in more details about that?

Comment: Yes sure. If you think that is the best option then I will work with that. Thanks

Comment: Atmel has a published application note that addresses sensorless Commutation of BLDC motors. It may provide some guidance: http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8306.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way for phase controlling the windings on DC Brushless motors is to use Hall Effect Sensors. Most of your better industrial motors come with these built right into the motor.

Your desire to avoid Hall Effect Sensors is an attempt at bucking against a proven reliable scheme. The schemes that you have mentioned thinking are are fraught with problems of noise, signal tolerances and current/voltage level changes with speed/temperature/load of the motor.

Comment: I see your point, but the motors I am using will be going on a quad-copter and they do not have a Hall Effect Sensor.

Comment: Many brushless DC motors have three winding phases that are driven 120 degrees out of phase. It takes three hall sensors to support the phase control for these motors. One sensor with trying to use fixed delays does not work properly when motor rotational speed changes.

Comment: Dr. Alain Cassat patented a method of detecting rotor position in a BLDC motor that is accurate enough for commutation even with the rotor stalled. (When there is no BEMF).  You can see how this works here: http://www.google.com/patents/US5001405